# Error when trying to use JWT for ASP NET Owin Authentication?

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, jwt, owin

I had the following configuration:

```
var oAuthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
        {
            AllowInsecureHttp = true,
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/token"),
            AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/authorize_endpoint"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AccessTokenTimeSpanInMinutes"])),
            AuthorizationCodeExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
            Provider = new ApiAuthorizationServerProvider(userRepository, externalAppRepository),
            RefreshTokenProvider = new ApiRefreshTokenProvider(),
            AuthorizationCodeProvider = new ApiExternalAuthenticationTokenProvider(externalAppRepository)
        };

        // Token Generation
        app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(oAuthServerOptions);
        app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());
```

I read somewhere that they added a `JwtFormat` object I could use in the options, by setting `AccessTokenFormat`, but when I did that and my options looked something like this:

```
var oAuthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
        {
            AllowInsecureHttp = true,
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/token"),
            AccessTokenFormat = new JwtFormat(new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("secretkey")),
                ValidateLifetime = false,
                ValidateIssuer = false,
                ValidateAudience = false
            }),
            AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/authorize_endpoint"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AccessTokenTimeSpanInMinutes"])),
            AuthorizationCodeExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
            Provider = new ApiAuthorizationServerProvider(userRepository, externalAppRepository),
            RefreshTokenProvider = new ApiRefreshTokenProvider(),
            AuthorizationCodeProvider = new ApiExternalAuthenticationTokenProvider(externalAppRepository)
        };

        // Token Generation
        app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(oAuthServerOptions);
        app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());
```

My `OnGrantResourceOwnerCredentials` method throws an exception of `MethodNotSupported`

StackTrace:

```
[NotSupportedException: Specified method is not supported.]
   Microsoft.Owin.Security.Jwt.JwtFormat.Protect(AuthenticationTicket data) +40
   Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth.<InvokeTokenEndpointAsync>d__8.MoveNext() +4143
   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +32
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +62
   Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth.<InvokeAsync>d__5.MoveNext() +1098
   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +32
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +62
   Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.<Invoke>d__5.MoveNext() +517
   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +32
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +62
   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.<RunApp>d__5.MoveNext() +197
   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +32
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +62
   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.<DoFinalWork>d__2.MoveNext() +184
   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +32
   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.StageAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult ar) +118
   System.Web.AsyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +510
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +220
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +134
```

From [what I've gathered](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/dn450167(v%3Dvs.111)), that exception is

> Thrown if the IssuingSecurityTokenProvider is not a SigningSecurityTokenProvider.

Could anyone shine some light on this?

Comment: did you find a solution to problem? I stumbled upon the same issue.

Comment: @stackunderflow to this day I couldn't figure it out, and still haven't. Hence why I simply didn't try migrating to the usage of JWT, and stick to machine-level tokens, which sucks as they can't be shared. If you ever manage to figure this out, for the life of me, post it as an answer, and I'll give you a bounty for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To generate JWT token, the library needs to execute the Protect() method. However Microsoft hasn't provided an implementation for the Protect() method (The error message gives a hint *"Specified method is not supported"* ). It only provides an implementation of Unprotect() method. You can verify this by peeking into the library using ILDASM.

So we cannot directly use *AccessTokenFormat = new JwtFormat()* to generate a JWT token.
That being said, to generate a JWT token, you need to write a custom class which implements ISecureDataFormat interface. This interface provides two methods Protect() and Unprotect(). To generate JWT token, you only need to implement Protect() method and use this class as access token format.

The below link gives a very good explanation of how to implement this class and it's usage.

https://bitoftech.net/2014/10/27/json-web-token-asp-net-web-api-2-jwt-owin-authorization-server/

Comment: I've almost set it up but I'm getting this nasty error `Could not load file or assembly 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)` For context: `<dependentAssembly> <assemblyIdentity name="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" /> <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0" /> </dependentAssembly>`

Comment: Check the web.config file for the assembly version and compare it with assembly version directly. Sometimes VS does not update the web.config file correctly and we have to manually update the version in config. In my case, I am using the latest version and here is the setting       <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.8.0.0" newVersion="6.8.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>

Comment: Thank you, yesterday I tackled with this for awhile, and it seemed that I had to update all owin packages to the latest version as some were outdated and were getting confused from where to load the resources.